# How to generate a 3d graph obtained by rotating a plane curve about the x-axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I want to generate this diagram. Can anyone help in doing this? I can't get it right. I have tried to do that with the following code but can't get the desired output.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{45}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{+90}{180}{+90}


\tikzset{surface/.style={draw=blue!70, fill=blue!40!white, fill opacity=.6}}


\newcommand{\coneback}[4][]{
  %% start at the correct point on the circle, draw the arc, then draw to the origin of the diagram, then close the path
  \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=#2, #1] (45-#4:#3) arc (45-#4:225+#4:#3) -- (O) --cycle;
  }
\newcommand{\conefront}[4][]{
  \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=#2, #1] (45-#4:#3) arc (45-#4:-135+#4:#3) -- (O) --cycle;
  }

\begin{document}{\LARGE {\tiny }}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  %% make sure to draw everything from back to front
  \draw[thick,color=green!100] (0,0,-5) -- (O);
  \draw[thick,->,color=green!100] (O) -- (0,0,5) node[left] {$x$};
   \draw[thick,->,color=red!100] (0,-6,0) -- (0,6,0) node[] {$y$};
  \conefront[surface]{3}{2}{10}
  \coneback[surface]{3}{2}{10}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! your "following code" is missing, please add it to your question ...

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={violet}{rgb255=(25,25,122) rgb255=(238,140,238) color=(white)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={10}{5},
mesh/interior colormap name=violet,
colormap/viridis,
xmin=-1, xmax=5,
ymin=-3, ymax=3,
zmin=-3, zmax=3,
axis lines=center, axis equal,
axis on top,
x axis line style={draw=none, insert path={(axis cs:-1,0,0) edge[-] (axis cs:0,0,0) (axis cs:0,0,0) edge[densely dashed, -, opacity=0.5] (axis cs:2.5,0,0) (axis cs:2.5,0,0) edge (axis cs:6,0,0)}},
y axis line style={draw=none, insert path={(axis cs:0,-3,0) edge[-] (axis cs:0,0,0) (axis cs:0,0,0) edge[opacity=0.3] (axis cs:0,3,0)}},
xtick distance=1, ztick distance=1,
ytick=\empty,
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=faceted interp,
domain=0:3, samples=10,
domain y=0:360, samples y=37,
z buffer=sort,
] (x,{x*cos(y)},{x*sin(y)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D shaded cone in coordinate system]

Answer (score 0):

[image: 23-16]

I tried to adapt in this case the code I developed for the question [Shading 3D arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/218261/daniel-n?tab=answers).  There are two problems to be handled:

1. the open cone (inner and outer faces)
2. the coordinate axis inside the cone.

I tried to obtain an image in which one can vary the position of the observer and the position of the light source.  Below is the same image from a slightly different point of view, for example.

[image]

The main `pic` object is `gen o-cone` which depend on six parameters.  This object produces a cone with some rulings drawn.  It is used by `oo-cone` which produces the cone with rulings and plane sections (the circles) drawn by successively drawing `gen o-cone`s sequentially.  The code is given first; it uses the file `tikzCone.sty`.  This file contains the definitions of the two `pic` objects, the point of view and the sun positions.  It appears at the end.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{tikzCone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[view={33}{26}, sun={-90}{70}{.9}]
  \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{middleground}  
  \pgfsetlayers{background, middleground, main}

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{middleground}
    \begin{scope}[blue!50!black, line width=1.2pt]
      \draw[red, ->] (0, 0, 0) -- (6, 0, 0)
      node[shift={(.2, 0, 0)}, above] {$x$};
      \draw[->] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 4, 0) node[shift={(-.1, .2, 0)}] {$y$};
      \draw[->] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 0, 4) node[shift={(-.1, 0, .3)}] {$z$};
    \end{scope}
  \end{pgfonlayer}

  \draw pic[blue!40!gray]
  {oo-cone={B=(0, 0, 0), T=(3, 0, 0), rB=0, rT=3.5, ng=11, ns=4}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**tikxCone.sty**

```
\tikzset{%
  view/.style 2 args={%  observer longitude and latitude (y upwards)
                      %  Remark. lomg=0 means x=0
    z={({-sin(#1)}, {-cos(#1)*sin(#2)})},
    x={({cos(#1)}, {-sin(#1)*sin(#2)})},
    y={(0, {cos(#2)})},
    evaluate={%
      \tox={sin(#1)*cos(#2)};
      \toy={sin(#2)};
      \toz={cos(#1)*cos(#2)};
    },
    longitude = #1,
    latitude = #2
  },
  sun/.style n args={3}{% longitude, latitude, light contrast in [0, 1]
    sun longitude = #1,
    sun latitude = #2,
    contrast = #3,
    evaluate={%
      real \sunx, \suny, \sunz, \lightC;
      \sunx = sin(\sLongit)*cos(\sLatit);
      \suny = sin(\sLatit);
      \sunz = cos(\sLongit)*cos(\sLatit);
    }
  }
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  latitude/.store in=\aLatit,  % observer's latitude
  latitude=0
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  longitude/.store in=\aLongit,  % observer's longitude
  longitude=0  % corresponds to x=0
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  sun latitude/.store in=\sLatit,
  sun latitude = 80
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  sun longitude/.store in=\sLongit, 
  sun longitude=90
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  contrast/.store in=\lightC,  % light contrast \in [0, 1]
  contrast=.5
}

\tikzmath{%
  function coneFaceIsSeen(\j, \M) {%
    \t = 360*((\j-.5)/\M);
    \ux = \vx*cos(\t) +\wx*sin(\t);
    \uy = \vy*cos(\t) +\wy*sin(\t);
    \uz = \vz*cos(\t) +\wz*sin(\t);
    % modification needed when the radii are different
    \ang = atan2(\coneBR -\coneTR, \tmpBT);
    \ux = \ux*cos(\ang) +\nx*sin(\ang);
    \uy = \uy*cos(\ang) +\ny*sin(\ang);
    \uz = \uz*cos(\ang) +\nz*sin(\ang);    
    \res = \ux*\tox + \uy*\toy + \uz*\toz;
    if \res >= 0 then { return 1;} else {return 0;};
  };
  function coneFaceColor(\j, \M) {
    % Verifies if seen when the cone has no base; the color number is
    % modified by -2000.
    real \ang;
    \t = 360*((\j-.5)/\M);
    \ux = \vx*cos(\t) +\wx*sin(\t);
    \uy = \vy*cos(\t) +\wy*sin(\t);
    \uz = \vz*cos(\t) +\wz*sin(\t);
    % modification needed when the radii are different
    \ang = atan2(\coneBR -\coneTR, \tmpBT);
    \ux = \ux*cos(\ang) +\nx*sin(\ang);
    \uy = \uy*cos(\ang) +\ny*sin(\ang);
    \uz = \uz*cos(\ang) +\nz*sin(\ang);    
    \res = \ux*\tox + \uy*\toy + \uz*\toz;
    \tmp = int(100*\lightC*(\ux*\sunx + \uy*\suny + \uz*\sunz));
    if \res>0 then {% if seen
      return \tmp;
    } else {return {-2000 +\tmp};};
  };  
}

\tikzset{%
  pics/gen o-cone/.style args={B=(#1), T=(#2), rB=#3, rT=#4, ng=#5, np=#6}{%
    % x, y, z of the bottom and top centers: #1 and #2
    % bottom and top radius: #3 and #4
    % number of generatrices to be drawn and of global points: #5 and #6
    code={%
      \colorlet{mainColor}{.}
      \colorlet{innerColor}{-mainColor!90!gray}
      \colorlet{lineRGB}{mainColor!30!black}
      \colorlet{leftRGB{0}}{mainColor!70!black}  % shade outside
      \colorlet{leftRGB{1}}{white}               % light outside
      \colorlet{leftRGB{2}}{innerColor!70!black}
      \colorlet{leftRGB{3}}{white}
      \colorlet{rightRGB{0}}{mainColor}       % shade outside
      \colorlet{rightRGB{1}}{mainColor}       % light outside
      \colorlet{rightRGB{2}}{innerColor}      % shade inside
      \colorlet{rightRGB{3}}{innerColor}      % light inside
      \tikzmath{%  B, T, rB, rT, and construction of the orthonormal basis
        integer \coneN, \k, \j, \prevj, \i, \ng, \ntmp;
        real \Bx, \By, \Bz, \Tx, \Ty, \Tz, \coneBR, \coneTR;
        \j = 0;
        for \c in {#1}{%
          \j = \j +1;
          \B{\j} = \c;
        };
        \j = 0;
        for \c in {#2}{%
          \j = \j +1;
          \T{\j} = \c;
        };
        \Bx = \B{1};
        \By = \B{2};
        \Bz = \B{3};
        \Tx = \T{1};
        \Ty = \T{2};
        \Tz = \T{3};
        \coneBR = #3;
        \coneTR = #4;
        \ng = #5;
        \ntmp = int(#6/\ng);
        \coneN = \ntmp*\ng;
        real \tmpBT, \tmpx, \tmpy, \tmpz, \tmpcst, \cstForColor;
        real \nx, \ny, \nz, \vx, \vy, \vz, \wx, \wy, \wz;
        \tmpx = \Tx -\Bx;
        \tmpy = \Ty -\By;
        \tmpz = \Tz -\Bz;
        \tmpBT = sqrt(\tmpx*\tmpx +\tmpy*\tmpy +\tmpz*\tmpz);
        \nx = \tmpx/\tmpBT;
        \ny = \tmpy/\tmpBT;
        \nz = \tmpz/\tmpBT;
        if abs(\ny)>=abs(\nz) then {%
          \tmpcst = sqrt(\nx*\nx +\ny*\ny);
          \vx = -\ny/\tmpcst;
          \vy = \nx/\tmpcst;
          \vz = 0;
          \wx = -\vy*\nz;
          \wy = \vx*\nz;
          \wz = (1 -\nz*\nz)/\tmpcst;
        } else {%
          \tmpcst = sqrt(\nx*\nx +\nz*\nz);
          \vx = -\nz/\tmpcst;
          \vy = 0;
          \vz = \nx/\tmpcst;
          \wx = \vz*\ny;
          \wy = (\ny*\ny -1)/\tmpcst;
          \wz = -\vx*\ny;
        };
        %% points \P {1,\j} for bottom, \P {2,\j} for top
        for \j in {0, ..., \coneN}{%
          \t = \j/\coneN*360;
          \Px{1,\j} = \Bx +\coneBR*\vx*cos(\t) +\coneBR*\wx*sin(\t);
          \Py{1,\j} = \By +\coneBR*\vy*cos(\t) +\coneBR*\wy*sin(\t);
          \Pz{1,\j} = \Bz +\coneBR*\vz*cos(\t) +\coneBR*\wz*sin(\t);
          \Px{2,\j} = \Tx +\coneTR*\vx*cos(\t) +\coneTR*\wx*sin(\t);
          \Py{2,\j} = \Ty +\coneTR*\vy*cos(\t) +\coneTR*\wy*sin(\t);
          \Pz{2,\j} = \Tz +\coneTR*\vz*cos(\t) +\coneTR*\wz*sin(\t);
        };
        %% lateral faces
        for \j in {1, ..., \coneN}{%
          \prevj = \j -1;
          \cstForColor = coneFaceColor(\j, \coneN);
          if \cstForColor>-999 then {%
            if \cstForColor>=0. then {%
              \i = 1;
            } else {%
              \i = 0;  % in shade
              \cstForColor = int(abs(\cstForColor));
            };
            {%
              \fill[leftRGB{\i}!\cstForColor!rightRGB{\i}]
              (\Px{1,\prevj}, \Py{1,\prevj}, \Pz{1,\prevj})
              -- (\Px{1,\j}, \Py{1,\j}, \Pz{1,\j})
              -- (\Px{2,\j}, \Py{2,\j}, \Pz{2,\j})
              -- (\Px{2,\prevj}, \Py{2,\prevj}, \Pz{2,\prevj})
              -- cycle;
              \draw[lineRGB, line width=.1pt]
              (\Px{1,\prevj}, \Py{1,\prevj}, \Pz{1,\prevj})
              -- (\Px{1,\j}, \Py{1,\j}, \Pz{1,\j});
              \draw[lineRGB, line width=.1pt]
              (\Px{2,\j}, \Py{2,\j}, \Pz{2,\j})
              -- (\Px{2,\prevj}, \Py{2,\prevj}, \Pz{2,\prevj});              
            };
            if int(\prevj/\ntmp)*\ntmp==\prevj then {%
              {%
                \draw[lineRGB]
                (\Px{1,\j}, \Py{1,\j}, \Pz{1,\j})
                -- (\Px{2,\j}, \Py{2,\j}, \Pz{2,\j});
              };
            } else {%
              {%
                \draw[leftRGB{\i}!\cstForColor!rightRGB{\i}]
                (\Px{1,\j}, \Py{1,\j}, \Pz{1,\j})
                -- (\Px{2,\j}, \Py{2,\j}, \Pz{2,\j});
              };
            };
          } else {%
            \cstForColor = -(\cstForColor +2000);  % back to -value
            if \cstForColor>=0. then {%
              \i = 3;
            } else {%
              \i = 2;  % in the shade for leftRGB{}
              \cstForColor = int(abs(\cstForColor));
            };
            {%
              \begin{pgfonlayer}{background} 
                \fill[leftRGB{\i}!\cstForColor!rightRGB{\i}]
                (\Px{1,\prevj}, \Py{1,\prevj}, \Pz{1,\prevj})
                -- (\Px{1,\j}, \Py{1,\j}, \Pz{1,\j})
                -- (\Px{2,\j}, \Py{2,\j}, \Pz{2,\j})
                -- (\Px{2,\prevj}, \Py{2,\prevj}, \Pz{2,\prevj})
                -- cycle;
                \draw[lineRGB, line width=.1pt]
                (\Px{1,\prevj}, \Py{1,\prevj}, \Pz{1,\prevj})
                -- (\Px{1,\j}, \Py{1,\j}, \Pz{1,\j});
                \draw[lineRGB, line width=.1pt]
                (\Px{2,\j}, \Py{2,\j}, \Pz{2,\j})
                -- (\Px{2,\prevj}, \Py{2,\prevj}, \Pz{2,\prevj});
              \end{pgfonlayer}
            };
            if int(\prevj/\ntmp)*\ntmp==\prevj then {%
              {%
                \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
                  \draw[lineRGB, line width=.1pt]
                  (\Px{1,\j}, \Py{1,\j}, \Pz{1,\j})
                  -- (\Px{2,\j}, \Py{2,\j}, \Pz{2,\j});
                \end{pgfonlayer}
              };
            } else {%
              {%
                \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
                  \draw[leftRGB{\i}!\cstForColor!rightRGB{\i}]
                  (\Px{1,\j}, \Py{1,\j}, \Pz{1,\j})
                  -- (\Px{2,\j}, \Py{2,\j}, \Pz{2,\j});
               \end{pgfonlayer}
              };
            };            
          };
        };
      }  % end tikzmath
    }
  },
  pics/oo-cone/.style args={B=(#1), T=(#2), rB=#3, rT=#4, ng=#5, ns=#6}{%
    % cone surface with a mesh of generatrices and sections
    % x, y, z of the bottom and top centers: #1 and #2
    % bottom and top radius: #3 and #4
    % number of generatrices to be drawn and of sections: #5 and #6
    code={%
      \tikzmath{%
        integer \previ, \j, \prevj, \i, \ng, \ns, \nextNs, \ntmp;
        real \Bx, \By, \Bz, \Tx, \Ty, \Tz, \coneBR, \coneTR;
        \ns = #6;
        \j = 0;
        for \c in {#1}{%
          \j = \j +1;
          \P{0,\j} = \c;
        };
        \j = 0;
        for \c in {#2}{%
          \j = \j +1;
          \P{\ns,\j} = \c;
        };        
        \P{0,4} = #3;
        \P{\ns,4} = #4;
        for \j in {1, ..., 4}{%
          \d{\j} = (\P{\ns,\j} -\P{0,\j})/\ns;
        };
        \ng = #5;
        for \i in {1, ..., \ns}{%
          \previ = \i -1;
          for \j in {1, 2, 3, 4}{%
            \P{\i,\j} = \P{\previ,\j} +\d{\j};
          };
          {%
            \path pic[.]
            {gen o-cone={B=(\P{\previ,1}, \P{\previ,2}, \P{\previ,3}),
                T=(\P{\i,1}, \P{\i,2}, \P{\i,3}),
                rB=\P{\previ,4}, rT=\P{\i,4}, ng=12, np=240}};
          };
        };
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would just make this in GeoGebra or a similar program specialized for doing it, take a screenshot, and input the image with \includegraphics{}

Comment: The point is not to create the image using whatever software can be found there, but to do it using Tikz (and its limited 3d capacities).  This forum is about Tikz and not about POV-Ray for example!